# how to send emails to all domains( yahoo ,gmail , rediff ,hotmail, ect ...) from play 2.0 application?

Tags: email, playframework-2.0

I'm creating Play 2.0 application.  I need to send email to any domain (like Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail, Rediff, etc).  I used a Gmail server, so I need to be able to send to Gmail.  How can I send to all these SMTP providers?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that mean that your Gmail server can not send emails to Yahoo ? Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Play!2.0 mailer plugin

https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer

Comment: Thank you.Is there mailer plugin for java ?

Comment: It is also for Java. See the [README](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/blob/master/mailer/README.md) file how to use it from Java.